# Disable automatic updates (2012R2) with powershell

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012-r2

I saw some related questions but none of the solutions didn't work for me.
I have windows server 2012R2 and I need to disable it automatic windows updates with Powershell v5.0 or batch (Powershell is preferred).

I can do it manually, by opening `gpedit.msc` , navigating to `Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> Windows Components -> Windows Update` and then changing `Configure Automatic Updates` to `Disable`.

How can that be done automatically **without** using external powershell modules (such as `PolicyFileEditor`).

Is there an equivalent registry key that changing it can get the job done? I know that there is one for Windows server 2008 but I'm using 2012R2.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the [full list](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc708449(v=ws.10).aspx) of reg keys for Windows Update for reference, but if you set `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\AU\NoAutoUpdate` to `1` this disables Windows Update.

You can use [New-ItemProperty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-itemproperty?view=powershell-5.1) to set this value using PowerShell

Comment: Thanks, the key didn't exist so I had to create it, then it worked.

Comment: There is no such key in my *Windows* 2012 R2. Could tell us its type and provide the source of a .reg file to turn the setting off?

Comment: I have just added `regedit` samplle by editing your answer instead of creating a new one. I hope you don't mind.

Comment: Please add it as your own answer - my answer is PowerShell and different to creating a reg file.